# run two queries in firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code, i was trying to calculate the difference between sales and expenditure..Is there a way to find the difference between the result of dref and dreff???

```
dref= dref.child("KatakaExpenditure");
dreff= dreff.child("KatakaSales");

        dref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                int totalAmount = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    DogExpenditure dogExpenditure = postSnapshot.getValue(DogExpenditure.class);
                    totalAmount += dogExpenditure.getAmount();
                }


                textView4.setText("Your total expenses for Kataka Unit is:" +Integer.toString(totalAmount));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }


            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });

        dreff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                int totalAmountt = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    DogExpenditure dogExpenditure = postSnapshot.getValue(DogExpenditure.class);
                    totalAmountt += dogExpenditure.getAmount();
                }


                textView4.setText("Your total expenses for Kataka Unit is:" +Integer.toString(totalAmountt));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }


            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });


        textView4.setText("Your total expenses for Kataka Unit is:" +Integer.toString(totalAmountt));

int profit = totalAmountt - totalAmount;
Where totalAmount is the **dref= dref.child("KatakaExpenditure");
** and totalAmountt is **dreff= dref.child("KatakaSales");**
```

What i am trying to do is get the difference of the totals of two children in the databse...i realise that the two variables cannot be accessed outside their methods.

Comment: If you have access to the DB, just do it in a single Query

Comment: show me thats what i want

Comment: Show me? LOL Do some research and ask an accurate question regarding the issue. We won't do it for you.

Comment: i am asking how to do that with my current code...dont you se ihave already done something??? AND STOP BEING RUDE!!!!

Comment: _how can i achieve this??_ is not an accurate question. If you want us to help you, you have to show some effort, instead of insulting us. We do this for free, show some respect.

Comment: i just wanted to know how i can subtract totalAmountt of dreff -  totalAmount of dref..thats all?

Comment: i owe my career to stack overflow..i havent insulted anyone please..i would never insult anyone here